# This keyword in lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, this

I have 3 classes:

**Event**

```
 public class Event<T> {
        private List<BiConsumer<Object, T>> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
        public void subscribe(BiConsumer<Object, T> consumer) {
            consumers.add(consumer);
        }
        public void invoke(Object sender, T arg) {
            for (BiConsumer<Object, T> consumer : consumers) {
                System.out.println(sender  + " " + "sender");
                consumer.accept(sender, arg);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Rat:**

```
public class Rat  {
    private Game game;
    public Rat(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        game.ratEnters.subscribe((sender, arg) -> {
            System.out.println( this + " " + sender);
        });
        System.out.println(this + "this");
        game.ratEnters.invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

**Game:**

```
public class Game {
    public Event ratEnters = new Event();
}
```

and single test:

```
public class ObserverPatternTest {

    @Test
    public void singleRatTest() {
        Game game = new Game();
        Rat rat  = new Rat(game);
        Rat rat2 = new Rat(game);
        Rat rat3 = new Rat(game);
    }

}
```

**The output:**

```
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669this
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669 sender
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669 design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166this
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166 sender
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669 design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166 sender
design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166 design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166
```

My question is: how it is possible that this instance is not the same as sender instance?

design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@4e515669 design.patterns.behavioral.patterns.observer.exercises.Rat@17d10166

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to explain with an example completely. What happens with your code (*modified for a more readable output*) is as follows :

#### First Instance

```
Rat rat1 = new Rat(game);
```

is executed as :

```
this   ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8
pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8
```

Simple, right? I believe this was self-explanatory since a single instance(***4cf777e8***) created, just the list with one consumer and everything works as expected.

#### Second Instance

Then in the second initialization

```
Rat rat2 = new Rat(game);
```

you've now created another instance of `Rat`(***5702b3b1***) which becomes the `sender` now in your `Event.invoke` call as:

```
// part-1
this   ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1
// part-2
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1
pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1
pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1
```

the output that you see is divided into two parts, the first part prints the current instance of this and sender which is the latest instance created.

The second part is what is crucial since it now has the `List<BiConsumer<Object, T>>`, this list has a previous instance of `Rat`(***4cf777e8***) as well, and that's the reason when you perform `consumer.accept(sender, arg);`, the first instance comes into the picture, with `this` pointing to its instance and `sender` pointing to the current `sender` you've passed into the argument.

#### Third Instance

Further in the last initialization

```
Rat rat3 = new Rat(game);
```

you can now see how the list of `consumers` have grown and its impact on the output. Bear in mind that the list now has `BiConsumer`s, each for an instance of `Rat` created i.e. ***Rat(4cf777e8)***, ***Rat(5702b3b1)*** and ***Rat@69ea3742*** as you would observe in the output.

```
// part-1
this   ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742
// part-2
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742
pack.Sample$Rat@4cf777e8  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742 // (first element in list)
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742
pack.Sample$Rat@5702b3b1  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742 // (second element in list)
sender     ---->   pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742
pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742  this   ---->  sender  pack.Sample$Rat@69ea3742 // (third element in list)
```

---

#### Simplified

A simplified version of your code to test that I came up with :

```
public static class Event {
    private List<Consumer<Object>> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

    void subscribe(Consumer<Object> consumer) {
        consumers.add(consumer);
    }

    void invoke(Object sender) {
        consumers.forEach(consumer -> {
            System.out.println("sender     ---->   " + sender);
            consumer.accept(sender);
        });
    }
}

public static class Rat {
    private Game game;

    Rat(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        System.out.println("this   ---->   " + this);
        game.ratEnters.subscribe((sender) -> System.out.println(this + "  this   ---->  sender  " + sender));
        game.ratEnters.invoke(this);
    }
}

public static class Game {
    Event ratEnters = new Event();
}
```